# Determine if field exists in client-side object model?

Tags: 2010, development, csom

I want to check to see if a field exists in my program, but If I use :

```
if (item[_strContainingFieldName] != null)
{
    item[_strContainingFieldName] = fieldValue;
}
```

I receive an error stating

> The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

So I wanted to use `List.Fields.ContainsField` or `properties.ListItem.Fields.ContainsField` but forgot I can only use these in the server API.

Is there something similar which I can make use of right now? The tool will be a "throw away" application since we're making updates behind the scenes, so I'm not too worried about catching every possibility and logging everything.

Note: The language is C#

Comment: What language are you writing the script in?

Comment: C#. I tried to put it as a tag and it wouldn't accept it. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error i think you are using CSOM. If yes, then you have to load the properties before using it.

```
context.Load(item); 
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

To check if field exists use following:

```
if(item.FieldValues.ContainsKey("salesdate"))
```

Comment: I did this, so my updates to fields which exist are fine. But when I enter a field that doesn't exist, I want it to be skipped (so I users enter a field that is nonexistent, it should be skipped).

Comment: you can check as if(item.FieldValues.ContainsKey("salesdate"))

Comment: Thanks! Can you add this comment to your answer? I will mark it accordingly.

Comment: updated the answer.